# Solving Differential Equation -trouble-

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equations: $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} - \dfrac{1}{x}y = \dfrac{1}{x^3}y^2,$$ and $y(1) = 1$, I am supposed to solve for $y$.

Eventually through my work, I find $$x^{\color{red}1}v = -\int \dfrac{1}{x^\color{red}2}\,dx,$$ where $v = y^{-1}$. So, $v =- x^{-1} \left [  \frac{1}{-1}x^{-1} + C \right ]$. I tried substituting $y^{-1}$ for $v$, but I am unable to solve for $y$ alone. Ideas?

I get my answer to be: $$y = x^2$$ but that is wrong

Comment: If the question is not a duplicate, consider posting an answer to your own question rather than trying to delete it. MSE Q&A are as much meant to benefit the Internet as a whole as they are the asker.

Comment: @G.H.Faust Updated with an answer I found. It's incorrect though.

Comment: Your substitution works to get your DE into a nice/easy form. Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) will tell you what you need to proceed. Edit: actually, rereading your post it looks like you may have just made a simple error by dividing by an integrating factor rather than multiplying.

Comment: is it true @nomlelyn

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- By trial and error, divide by $-y^2(x)$ (makes the derivative easier to deal with).
- Let:

$$v(x) = \dfrac{1}{y(x)}$$

- Find $v'$, and substitute these into ODE.
- This will give you an ODE that you can use Integrating Factor on.

**Spoiler**

> $$y(x) = x^2$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a Bernoulli differential equation, which takes the form of:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+g(x)y=h(x)y^n$$
The general way to solve this is to divide both sides by $y^n$ to get:
$$y^{-n}\frac{dy}{dx}+g(x)y^{1-n}=h(x)$$
Set $v=y^{1-n}$, and therefore $\frac{dv}{dx}=(1-n)y^{-n}\frac{dy}{dx}$. Solving for $y^{-n}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1{1-n}\frac{dv}{dx}$ and making all the substitutions yields:

$$\frac1{1-n}\frac{dv}{dx}+g(x)v=h(x)$$

which is a first order linear differential equation and can be solved from there.

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{x\frac{dy}{dx}-y}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}(\frac{y}{x})^2$$ or
 $$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{y}{x})=\frac{1}{x^2}(\frac{y}{x})^2.$$ By substituting $z=\frac{y}{x}$, we get $$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{z^2}{x^2}$$ or $$\frac{dz}{z^2}=\frac{dx}{x^2},$$ from where we get $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{x}+C$ and $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{1}{x}+C$. Then, $$y=\frac{x}{C+\frac{1}{x}}.$$ Since $y(1)=1$, we have $C=0$ and final solution is $y=x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{1}{X}y=\frac{1}{x^3}{y^2}$

Let $v=\frac{v}{x} \therefore \frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$

$v+x\frac{dv}{dx}-v=\frac{1}{x}v^{2}$

$x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}v^{2}$

$\int\frac{1}{x^2}dx=\int \frac{1}{v^2}dv$

We get

$-2(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{v^3})=C$

$-2(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{x^3}{y^3})=C$

Replacing $x=1,y=1$ we get C=4

Placing on same common denominator

$\frac{y^3+x^6y^3}{y^3x^3}=2$

$y^3+x^6y^3=2y^3x^3$

$(y^{\frac{3}{2}}-x^3)^2=0$

$y^{\frac{3}{2}}=x^3$

$\therefore y=x^2$